# Gitlab git authentification in pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, maven-scm-plugin

I am try to change my app version and push it on manual pipeline in Gitlab.

I change version with maven and using maven smc pluggin to push.

When the pipeline run and give me this error :

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Cloning into '/builds/MYPROJECT/target/checkout'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'gitlabAdress': No such device or address
```

So I understand there is no credential to run git command.

Is there a gitlab user to do that? 
May be I have to use token?

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: `[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/MYPROJECT/target' && 'git' 'clone' 'gitlabAdress/MYPROJECT.git' '/builds/MYPROJECT/target/checkout'`